# Rsync exclude problems

Tags: rsync

I have a huge amount of directories with a similar subfolder structure. Each dir has a subdir "s". Some dirs have a "_tmp" -prefix in the name.

What I want is to copy all the main dirs to a new server, but leave the s-subdirs and _tmp -dirst out of the transfer.

On OSX (rsync v. 2.6.9) this command works fine:

```
rsync -avz --exclude */s/* --exclude *_tmp SOURCE/ DEST/
```

But on Ubuntu (rsync v. 3.0.7) the same command fails, _tmps are out but the s-folders are still in. Any workarounds?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask you to prepend your command with `echo` to see what you are running.

`echo rsync -avz --exclude */s/* --exclude *_tmp SOURCE/ DEST/`

Depending on your shell, your shell settings, and the contents of your current directory, the unquoted `*_tmp` may be expanded into a particular file (which probably won't match most of the ones you want to exclude).  The `echo` should show what is actually happening.

You should protect the asterisks with quotes to prevent shell expansion.

`rsync -avz --exclude '*/s/*' --exclude '*_tmp' SOURCE/ DEST/`